# How to show <li> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with JQuery i couldn't solved.

In jQuery:

```
$airlineli.filter(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == "checked") {
        var pana = $(this).children('input').attr("data-airline");
        $('li[data-airline=pana]').show();
    }
});
```

How to use `pana` in `$('li[data-airline=pana]').show();` ?

Comment: Provide the relevant html as per [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build your selector to explicitly target the specific elements with that attribute by using an [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
// Get your attribute
var pana = $(this).children('input').attr("data-airline");
// Target all list elements with that given attribute value
$('li[data-airline="' + pana + '"]').show();
```